# Why do I get a black screen when loading tmx file using andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am trying to load a tmx file to my 2D android game, but all I get is a black screen. I don't even have any errors to debug.I don't know where did it went wrong.
**Here is my activity**

```
package com.example.parkmycar;

import org.andengine.engine.Engine;
import org.andengine.engine.LimitedFPSEngine;
import org.andengine.engine.camera.BoundCamera;
import org.andengine.engine.options.EngineOptions;
import org.andengine.engine.options.ScreenOrientation;
import org.andengine.engine.options.resolutionpolicy.RatioResolutionPolicy;
import org.andengine.entity.scene.Scene;
import org.andengine.entity.util.FPSLogger;
import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLayer;
import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXLoader;
import org.andengine.extension.tmx.TMXTiledMap;
import org.andengine.extension.tmx.util.exception.TMXLoadException;
import org.andengine.opengl.texture.TextureOptions;
import org.andengine.ui.activity.SimpleBaseGameActivity;





public class GameActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity {



    private static final int CAMERA_WIDTH = 550;
    private static final int CAMERA_HEIGHT = 300;


    private BoundCamera mBoundChaseCamera;

    private TMXTiledMap mTMXTiledMap;
    protected int mCactusCount;
    private TMXLayer tmxLayer;

    @Override
    public Engine onCreateEngine(EngineOptions engineOptions){
        //Creating our customized engine
        return new LimitedFPSEngine(engineOptions,60) ;     
    }

    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {

        this.mBoundChaseCamera = new BoundCamera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mBoundChaseCamera);
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreateResources() {

          final TMXLoader tmxLoader = new TMXLoader(getAssets(), getTextureManager(), TextureOptions.NEAREST, mEngine.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
          try {
                this.mTMXTiledMap = tmxLoader.loadFromAsset("tmx/3afak.tmx");
            } catch (TMXLoadException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Problem in loading the tmx file");
            }   

    }   


    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {

        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
        final Scene scene = new Scene();      
        this.tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0);  // the 0 is just an index of the layer. It depends on how many layers you created within Tiled

        scene.attachChild(tmxLayer) ;
        scene.setScale(1.5f);



    /*  this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBounds(0, 0, tmxLayer.getHeight(), tmxLayer.getWidth());
        this.mBoundChaseCamera.setBoundsEnabled(true);
*/  

        return scene;

    }       

}
```

**And here is my tmx file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map version="1.0" orientation="orthogonal" renderorder="right-down" width="15" height="15" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" nextobjectid="1">
 <tileset firstgid="1" name="grass" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="36">
  <image source="gfx/grass.jpg" width="200" height="200"/>
 </tileset>
 <layer name="Tile Layer 1" width="15" height="15">
  <data encoding="base64" compression="gzip">
   H4sIAAAAAAAAC42Q1w7CMBAEYwihhpJQTA3F//+NrKU96WSdDQ8jhTuPd01dVdUUtApHRmAMajABTTJ3PN8Xzlu+Y2bOaYws646cuyrsS7nR6/58u+X5H++2XPEe6q70PTlXvKA6pL1yrnhBdUh7lf4r7Ul3yYyzlv4MzMECLLkPRnfJjLOe/hpswBbsuA/K85xJZpyd6e/BARzBSe2DusOrzDgb6F/AFdzAnfs3+Bi+9H/Rf/Jbn09/i9+RL3n27EWEAwAA
  </data>
 </layer>
</map>
```

I am using the last version of andengine GLS2 and working on a tablet (zync 930+).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Andengine loading graphics: why is my background texture small and upside down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33851112/andengine-loading-graphics-why-is-my-background-texture-small-and-upside-down)

Comment: Don't think its the same since that was a texture and this is a TMX file.

Comment: @haikei put this in your Catch ```Debug.e(e);``` . should give you a more useful error.

Answer (score 0):

I disabled the background and set the sceneChildren to invisible, and the black screen disappeared.

```
@Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        final Scene scene = new Scene();  

        this.tmxLayer = this.mTMXTiledMap.getTMXLayers().get(0); 

        scene.setChildrenVisible(false);
        scene.setBackgroundEnabled(false);
        tmxLayer.setScale(0.5f) ; 
        scene.attachChild(tmxLayer) ;


    return scene;

    }
```

But still I don't get what I am supposed to have. Here is a capture:
[image]
I already had this problem when I was trying to load my menu scene background, but scaling the background sprite fixed it. I don't know what to do in this case, my tmxLayer is already scaled before being attached to the scene!!